# Debugging JSON Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am learning Javascript and have been following a tutorial on coding an autofill search box. I have got so far but am now stuck on parsing some JSON code. The JSON code is the result of a PHP SELECT from my database.

The JSON result looks like the below.

```
   ["Leeds","Leicester"]
```

According to JSONLint it is valid JSON code.

However when I run the snippet of code below I get a script 1014 Invalid Character at the jQuery.parseJSON line...................I know its something to do with the fact that my JSON code is not an object but cannot work out what to do. I even tried stringify on the data before parsing but that did not work either

```
  ................other code 
  $.get("No1PHPfile.php",{keyword:keyword})
  .done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var results=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  console.log(results);
  ...................other code
```

EDIT

Two sets of PHP Files

No. 1

```
<?php

   require('..........sqldatabase.php');
   require('.........selectdatabasecode.php');

   if(!isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    die();
   }

   $keyword=$_GET['keyword'];
   $data=searchForKeyword($keyword);
   echo json_encode($data);


   ?>
```

No. 2

```
<?php

   function getDbconnection() {
    $db=new PDO(DB_DRIVER.":dbname=".DB_DATABASE.";host=".DB_SERVER.";charset=utf8",DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $db;
    }

   function searchForKeyword($keyword) {
    $db=getDbconnection();
    $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT stationlong FROM `station` WHERE stationlong LIKE ? ORDER BY stationlong ");
    $keyword=$keyword.'%';
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$keyword,PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
    $isQueryOk=$stmt->execute();
    $results=array();

    if ($isQueryOk) {
     $results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
     } else {
     trigger_error('Error Executing Staement.',E_USER_ERROR);
     }
     $db=null;

     return $results;

    }   

   ?>
```

Comment: Where is the PHP part?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$result = json_encode ($data_i_want_to_send);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $result;
```

may help

**UPD**

Yes. i'm sclerotic((
Try

```
$data=searchForKeyword($keyword);
$data=array ('data' => $data);   // so you send OBJECT anyway
$data=json_encode($data);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $data;
```

and on client side

```
var results= data.data;  // instead of jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

It should help to avoid different "magic" differences how it interpret your data and it works for sure in my site.

Comment: My opinion has not changed)) encode the result and add the header

Comment: Oh, sorry ... just add the header before echo

Comment: Putting the header in seems to stop the echo happening. If I remove the header line it echo's ["Leeds","Leicester"]

Comment: I also think the javascript get function may not be pulling the json code through anyway and thats where my problem might be. ie console.log(data) may be blank

Comment: the echo of the json now gives {"data":["Leeds","Leicester"]} however I still have to remove the header line to make that work. Otherwise blank. I am also getting an undefined now on the console

Comment: Thanks for your help al. I will continue to try some alternatives

Comment: After reviewing the tutorial again (by fully downloading the code) I found I was missing JSON_HEX_APOS. So my code should have read echo json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_APOS); instead of just echo json_encode($data);